# why the normal counter runs only last setCount argument and functional counter runs all setCount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Why the first one is only running the last setCount argument and when we are using the arrow function for setCount it's running both the argument.

eg: if you click the Normal button the *count* will be **5** as it should be **9**
If you click the Functional button the *count* will be **2** as it is running both the SetCount

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 console.log(count);
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <button
       onClick={() => {
         setCount(count + 1);
         setCount(count + 3);
         setCount(count + 5);
       }}
     >
       Normal
     </button>
     <br />

     <button
       onClick={() => {
         setCount((c) => c + 1);
         setCount((c) => c + 1);
       }}
     >
       Functional
     </button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Good question. 1 difference is that: `setstate((state) => state + 1)` is not dependent on the variable name and can be rewritten to `setstate((s) => s + 1)`